# Uses of "SE" : se discutió

Tags: selección-de-palabras, reflexivos, voz-pasiva, se

Can you see the difference between no. 6 and no. 7?
Are there any differences in meaning?
Could you please answer the questions below?

> 6, En el coloquio se discutió un tema interesante.

- 6a, In the symposium people discussed an interesting subject, OR In the symposium an interesting subject was discussed, (which one is correct?)
- 6b, tipo de SE: marca de impersonalidad o pasiva refleja (¿Cuál es correcto o ambos?)

> 7, En el coloquio se discutió de un tema interesante.

- 7a, In the symposium they argued with each other for an interesting subject.
- 7b, Tipo de "SE": con valor recíproco

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to RAE in this [link](http://buscon.rae.es/dpdI/SrvltGUIBusDPD?lema=discutir&origen=RAE):

> **discutir**. ‘Contraponer opiniones sobre algo’. Puede ser **transitivo**: «Discutieron la conveniencia de comprar algunos libros de ocultismo» o **intransitivo**, caso en el que lleva un complemento con **sobre, de o acerca de**: «Discutieron de platos y de precios» ; «Un grupo de diplomáticos hipócritas discutían sobre la paz» (Jodorowsky Danza [Chile 2001]).

It means that:

- **Discutir + sobre  + something**-> intransitive use
- **Discutir + de  + something**-> intransitive use
- **Discutir + acerca de  + something**-> intransitive use
- **Discutir + something** -> transitive use

So in your example:

> 6, En el coloquio se **discutió** un tema interesante.

In this first sentence as discutir is used in a transitive way and it is an example of **passive voice** (pasiva refleja) and it would be the same as saying this:

> En el coloquio un tema interesante fue discutido

so it could be translated as: "In the symposium an interesting subject was discussed". Here "se" marks that this sentence is a passive voice (pasiva refleja).

On the other hand:

> 7, En el coloquio se **discutió de** un tema interesante.

This second sentence is an example of intransitive use of that verb because it's followed by the preposition "de". As it is instransitive then it can't be a passive voice.

I'd say that in this case it is an **impersonal sentence**. and its meaning would be something like: "In the symposium people discussed an interesting subject". Here "se" marks that this sentence is impersonal.